# How can I stop an enum from converting to int when storing in a variable?

Tags: c++, enums

I have a header file, that looks like this:

```
namespace MyEnumNamespace
{
    enum class MyEnum
    {
    One,
    Two,
    Three
    };
}

class TestClass {
    public:
        TestClass();

        void setMyEnum(MyEnumNamespace::MyEnum e);

        void doOtherStuff(MyEnumNamespace::MyEnum e);

        void doStuff();
    private:
        MyEnumNamespace::MyEnum mEnum;
}
```

And a cpp that looks like this:

```
TestClass() {
    setMyEnum(MyEnumNamespace::MyEnum::One);
    doStuff();
}

void TestClass::setMyEnum(MyEnumNamespace::MyEnum e) {
    mEnum = e;
}

void TestClass::doOtherStuff(MyEnumNamespace::MyEnum e) {

}

void TestClass::doStuff() {
    doOtherStuff(e);
}
```

When calling the class I get the following error:

> error C2672: 'doOtherStuff': no matching overloaded function found

I already tried to call "doOtherStuff" on it's own and it worked like intended. I guess the enum gets converted to an int and the compiler can't find a fitting function-overload. I'm relatively new to c++ and don't really know how to revert this conversion, stop it entirely or what specific thing I have to google to find a solution.

Is there a way to do this without changing the parameters?

Comment: Why do you think it's being converted to an `int`?

Comment: Is there more to the error? I cannot reproduce this, it compiles fine here: https://godbolt.org/z/4558jTcx4 (assuming you meant `doOtherStuff(mEnum)` and not `doOtherStuff(e)`)

Comment: Please try to create a proper [mre] to show us. For example, in `doOtherStuff(e)` what is `e`? Also copy-paste the full anbd complete build-log into the question.

Comment: @Artyer: You fixed the bug in the process of making the godbolt test, fixing `e` (an argument to other methods, but not to `doStuff`) to make it `mEnum`. I'm voting to close as a typo (which is also the close reason when it's not reproducible, but it is in fact reproducible).

Comment: I rolled back the edit (again), because, as I tried to explain in comment on the answer, your edit renders an answer that is ok for the current state of the question into nonsense. The answer suggests to change your code to write `doOtherStuff(mEnum);`. That doesnt make sense when that is the code in the question.

Comment: The code provided does not produce the error cited.

Comment: no it doesnt and fwiw, neither does the code in the edit I rolled back https://godbolt.org/z/MMxYP5aM5. Modifying your code before posting here is ok, but you need to try to compile the code you post here, because others will do that too. If there are many other errors but not the one you report we cannot help

Answer (score 1):

Your problem is that `e` doesn't exist in `doStuff` (it's a parameter to some of your other functions, but not to `doStuff`). You meant:

```
doOtherStuff(mEnum);
```

to use the member variable. It's possible it's not realizing that `e` doesn't exist because a variable `e` was defined in global state that it is trying to use.

Comment: Yep my bad. It should have been "mEnum" in the question and not "e". Missed that in my proof read. But the error is still in my code. The function does accept "MyEnumNamespace::MyEnum::One" when called alone but it does not accept my member variable and I don't have the slightest clue why

Comment: @user22502145 please post a [mcve] in the question and the error you get from that code. If you show us other code that produces different / no errors we cannot help you

Comment: @user22502145 dont change the question to ask for something else after you recieved answers. In particular you should not fix an error taht was pointed out by an answer, not if the answer does not get updated also.

Comment: If I correct your constructor definition and fix your typo as suggested by the answer, your code appears to compile just fine for me.